# Mui Select change sides of arrow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, select, material-ui

I am using Select from Mui.
The arrow is default in the right side and the label on the left. I want them to change sides, so the label will be on the right and the arrow of the Select to be on the left.

This is my code, I am using Next.js:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel id="simple-select">{FilterTexts.FILTER_SORT_BY}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="simple-select"
    label={FilterTexts.FILTER_SORT_BY}
    sx={{
      maxWidth: { xs: smallWidth, sm: mediumWidth, md: width },
      minWidth: { xs: smallWidth, sm: mediumWidth, md: width },
      minHeight: height,
      maxHeight: height,
    }}
    value={filterSortBy}
    onChange={(e) => handleSortByChange(e.target.value as SortByType)}
  >
    {sortByButtons.map((button, index) => (
      <MenuItem key={index} value={button.value}>
        {button.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

I am building a website not in English, so the design should be the opposite side.